# Can't find the right formula in Excel

Tags: excel

I have 3 conditions based on this table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAeT0.png

Conditions are:

In column "Stadiu" (starting from D5) should type:

- `RIDICATA` if the number from `Populatie` is > 1000 and the column `Eveniment` has `Mondiala` in it
- `MEDIE` if the number from `Populatie` is > 500 or <= 1000 and the column `Eveniment` has `Mondiala`
- `MEDIE` if the number from `Populatie` is > 500 and the column `Eveniment` has `Internationala`
- `SLABA` = rest

I tried this formula:

```
=IF(AND(C5>1000;FIND("Mondiala";A5));"ridicata";IF(AND(C5>500;C5<=1000;FIND("Mondiala";A5));"medie";IF(AND(C5>500;FIND("Internationala";A5));"medie";IF(AND(C5<500);"slaba"))))
```

but it doesn't work.

I am new to Excel, so I hope you guys can help me what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Can you repair it please? I can't find the good formula, I don't know what to edit in the formula to make it good. Pls.

Comment: I can put the excel document here, if you can help me, I just need help. I have been trying to do it correct for 2 days now, and I don't know what to modify, I am just learning to do things like this in excel. But it's okay if you don't want, thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When evaluating the formula, anywhere that the `FIND` function doesn't find the string you're searching for, it returns a `#VALUE` error instead of `0` or `FALSE`. That's causing the whole formula to fail in those circumstances, so you need to handle those cases with `IFERROR`.

In addition, your nesting wasn't quite correct. You did not have an `ELSE` result for cases where all three tests failed. The following formula should return the expected results based on your criteria provided:

```
=IF(AND(C5>1000;IFERROR(FIND("Mondiala";A5);0));"Ridicata";IF(OR(AND(C5>500;C5<=1000;IFERROR(FIND("Mondiala";A5);0));AND(C5>500;IFERROR(FIND("Internationala";A5);0)));"Medie";"Slaba"))
```

Might be a little easier to relate it to your test criteria by spreading it out into sections:

```
=IF(
    AND(
        C5>1000;
        IFERROR(FIND("Mondiala";A5);0)
        );
        "Ridicata";

    IF(
        OR(
            AND(
                C5>500;
                C5<=1000;
                IFERROR(FIND("Mondiala";A5);0)
                );
            AND(
                C5>500;
                IFERROR(FIND("Internationala";A5);0)
                )
            );
            "Medie";

            "Slaba"
        )
    )
```

Comment: Hello can you help me with something? At school I have to use , in formula not ; as I am used to.

Comment: Do you know how can I set it to ; ? so the formula should be : =IF(AND(C5>1000;IFERROR(FIND("Mondiala";A5);0)) not =IF(AND(C5>1000,IFERROR(FIND("Mondiala",A5),0))